# Elastic search analyzers

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I want to specify per field analyzers in elasticsearch. For some fields I need the keyword analyzer, while for one I need a custom number analyzer that will remove all non-digit characters (see `number_analyzer` in below code)

The request that creates the index is

```
{
  "settings": {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "number_analyzer" : {
                   "type": "custom",
                   "tokenizer": "keyword",
                   "filter": ["lowercase"],
                   "char_filter": ["number_filter"]
                }
            },
            "char_filter" : {
                 "number_filter" : {
                     "type": "pattern_replace",
                     "pattern": "[\\d]+",
                     "replacement": ""
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The mapping for the fields is

```
{
        "properties": {
            "field1": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "yes",
                "index": "analyzed",
                "analyzer": "number_analyzer"
            },
            "field2": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "yes",
                "index": "not_analyzed",
                "analyzer": "keyword"
            },
            "field3": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "true",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "field4": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "yes",
                "index": "analyzed"
            },
            "field5": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "yes",
                "index": "analyzed",
                "analyzer": "number_analyzer"
            }
        }
}
```

When I insert the following document in the index

```
{
    "field1" : "464533AB",
    "field2" : "Euro",
    "field3" : "THIS IS A TITLE",
    "field4": "DEED_TYPE",
    "field5":"TEST3"
}
```

I notice that the characters from field1 are not removed (my goal is to keep `464533` only) and also that I am able to get results for the query `field4:DEED_TYPE`, although I shouldn't (I think that the standard analyzer will remove the special character and perform lowercase, so I'd expect `field4:DEED_TYPE` to work only with keyword analyzer).

Is there any error in the way the analyzers are specified in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the same analysis rules will be applied at query time, as are applied at index time.  So when you search for:

```
field4:"DEED_TYPE"
```

that query will be analyzed, and become:

```
field4:"deed type"
```

Similarly, analysis does not affect the stored version of the field, which I believe is what you are referring to in field1.  The stored version of the field, that is, the version retrieved from the index as a search result.  So even if the letters are removed in analysis, that will only be reflected in how you are able to search the data.  If you *want* to change the stored representation of a field, that should be done as pre-processing, before hitting lucene analysis.  Analyzers are not generally a tool used for that.

Your number_filter is wrong though, you have it backwards.  Should be:

```
"number_filter" : {
    "type": "pattern_replace",
    "pattern": "[^\\d]+",
    "replacement": ""
}
```

`[\\d]+` matches all digits.  By your description, you want to remove everything but digits, thus `[^\\d]+`